# If you wan't to send emails to subscribers, what benefits does an SMTP server have over Gmail?

Tags: web-server, smtp, python, django, gmail

Let's assume I have a website with an active community. The interactions of my community makes me want to send 1000 Emails a day to some subscribers. Would a gmail account succeed at this task? From what point would it be wise to invest in a SMTP server and why?

Comment: free gmail or paid g suite?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur What would be the difference? Free gmail for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For free Gmail, the daily limit sending via SMTP is 100 messages per rolling 24 hours. (NOT per day). If you want to send 1000 emails per day, it's impossible. [reference](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/47871468?hl=en)

For G Suite, messages per day is 2000, so you can use it if you only send 1000 emails per day.
[reference](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en)

The other reasons that why I don't recommend use Gmail as SMTP are:

- Based on my experience, usually the email go to spam box. (but depends on email content and recipient)
- High risk of suspend/disable your gmail/gsuite account, especially if you want to send blast/broadcast mail.
- TLS setting is required, maybe it will be secured but for some technically reason I don't like it.